# How to make parsedatetime ignore the colon after date?

Tags: python, datetime

I am reading a date string from a log file and converting it to date using `parsedatetime`:

```
c = parsedatetime.Calendar()
d = c.parse("29/May/2019:00:00:00 +0000")
```

which gives

```
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=17, tm_min=12, tm_sec=45, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=149, tm_isdst=1), 0)
```

where `tm_hour`, `tm_min`, `tm_sec` correspond to the current time, rather than being 0 as in the date string passed to `parse`.  If I remove the `:` after the year, I get the right output:

```
d = c.parse("29/May/2019 00:00:00 +0000")
```

which gives

```
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=29, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=149, tm_isdst=1), 2)
```

I don't like to modify my date string because that forces me to assume the date format.

Is there a way to make `parse` ignore the `:` after the year?

Comment: My answer will not force you to assume the date format as it will only replace the first colon, no matter where it is found

Comment: If you truly cannot use my answer, I don't think there is a way to do what you are asking

Comment: Opened an issue on github: https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/issues/235

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can do this using by the `.replace` method, like so:

```py
c = parsedatetime.Calendar()
e = "29/May/2019:00:00:00 +0000"
e.replace(":", " ", 1)
d = c.parse(e)
```

The first line that I added first defines what you want to parse as a variable in order to make handling it much easier. The next line first finds all instances of a ":" in the string, as specified by the first argument. The second argument specifies what to replace it with, in this case, a space. The third (optional) argument specifies how many times to replace, starting from the left of the string. The default value for this argument is `all`, which replaces all instances of that character in the string.

You can find more information on the `.replace()` method [here.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/replace)

Comment: Ideally, I don't want to modify the date string.  Just added that bit to the question.